# RoR I18n - can I pair a yml translation file with a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm looking for a way to do one of the following:

- Make a view use a .yml locale file that has the same name and relative path as the view (e.g. When **/app/views/thingie/blah.html.erb** is rendered, it gets translated with **/config/locales/thingie/blah/.yml**)
- Declare, from within a view, which translation file/directory it should use.

Any nice solution for that one?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a shorter syntax. Let's say your controller is "User", and you're rendering the "index" action. You can use the key `.nameofthekey`, which will look for `user.index.nameofthekey`. It seems to me that's what you want. Otherwise, you can use localized templates.

You can read more about those at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Answer (score 0):

You can render a text or html from a translation instead of from a view directly in your controller e.g.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    render :html => t(:'views.pages.home.body.html')
  end
end
```

No views involved at all here, very useful for things like static content pages :)